# How do I set up a job alert to be specific to a company?

Tags: support, jobs

Say that I am interested in a specific company that I know advertises on Careers. How do I set up a job alert to get emails when this specific company posts a job.

I've tried to put the company name in the keywords box. I've tried with quotes around the company name. The results that I get are much more than just the company.

Here is an example alert utilizing Stack Exchange (because, why not?). It is not specific to SE though. My alert looks like this:

[image: Careers Job Alert]

This alert returns [806 jobs](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=%22Stack+Exchange%22). Which is rather large, considering Stack Exchange only has [4 openings right now](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/company/stack-exchange#jobs). This also makes the daily email rather useless, if I am watching one particular company.

How do I utilize the job alerts to watch a specific company or at least narrow it down from 100s+ possibilities to something more manageable?