# Improving search in Stack Overflow Careers?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, jobs

I was poking around on the careers site today, and I felt like the search functionality was a little limited/weak. Some examples:

- There is no way to search on a tag. So if you search for
  `[sql-server]` you will get jobs that are tagged as that, but you
  will also get jobs that are tagged Oracle but mention SQL somewhere
  in the ad.
- There is no way to search job titles and job titles appear to have
  little effect on the order of returned results. For example, if you
  search for `data` the first result or two might have `data` in the
  title, but then it might be another 30 results or so before you see
  another job title with `data` in it.

When performing a search for `data` on remote jobs, 101 results currently come up. Even though I'm only interested in the three jobs that have that in the title, I still need to sift through the other five pages of results to be sure there isn't anything else hiding in there I might be interested in.

I also think that the current functionality is good for finding jobs related to what you are searching for but aren't titled/tagged exactly as what you are searching for, but it might be nice to be able to limit on these when you want to.

Does anyone else think that searching by title and tag would be useful features?

Comment: Somewhat related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/262133/how-do-i-set-up-a-job-alert-to-be-specific-to-a-company

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanks for the feedback. Regarding tags, we do actually support filtering but it's just not well advertised. If you click a tag on a job detail page or the search results page, a tag-filtered search will be executed. You can edit the URL to do this for any string, e.g. http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/tag/javascript .

We also agree that job search can be made more powerful, and in fact, we're currently working on a medium-sized project to make search much more powerful. We should have something to show soon, hopefully in less than 6-8 weeks! :)

Comment: The tag search doesn't actually work.  Try looking at the [haskell tag](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/tag/haskell).  You'll find all sorts of jobs listed there that are not using the tag at all, but mention it in their ad (usually as a "bonus points for knowing Haskell or other FP language, but you won't actually get to write any, neenerneenrneenr").

Answer (score 17):

I do agree, although instead of overriding the current search functionality, it would be cool to have an "advanced search" option.

I think the current search function is useful if you want to search a singular keyword, and you're certain almost all of the results will be somewhat interesting.  It's quick and easy if you need that.

But I totally agree, for those that want to add some depth into their search, some more options would be nice.

Answer (score 8):

I would like some geographic filtering. Specifically I'd like an 'exclude-location' that lets me specify 'Not London'. For those that don't live in the UK - London is big, has a lot of high tech jobs there - which means it's disproportionately influential on job market. But it's also a place where if you're commuting for under an hour you're lucky, and house prices are insane.