# What does "maximum job matches" mean?

Tags: support, status-completed, jobs, email

I received an email from Careers that says:

> You’re currently receiving maximum job matches. We want to make sure that you receive the right services during your job search. In order to continue receiving maximum job matches, please confirm that you’re still **Actively Looking** for a job.

What does "maximum job matches" mean and how does it differ from what I'd receive if I don't click "I'm still actively looking"?

Comment: Do you see such message anywhere on the Careers site itself?

Comment: Also, sounds like it's related to Job Alerts which are sent via email, how many of these you have?

Comment: Received the same e-mail, no idea what that means.

Comment: @Marius well it's probably some automatic process, so no wonder many got it. You have Job Alerts in place?

Comment: @ShadowWizard No I don't use Job Alerts. I did use job search last week or so.

Comment: @Marius weird. Might be a bug, let's wait for a dev to check. :)

Comment: I don't have alerts set up either.  I haven't been able to get them to work how I want.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/262133/how-do-i-set-up-a-job-alert-to-be-specific-to-a-company

Comment: @Andy have a look on the comments discussion under Mike's answer, wonder if those things make more sense for you than for me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After re-reading the copy in that email with fresh eyes, we have to agree it's unclear. Sorry about that. "Maximum job matches" was intended to be an umbrella term for a couple things:

- Prioritization in our candidate database. When your Job Search Status is set as **Actively looking** we give your CV more weight when employers search the database for candidates.
- [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) Personalized job recommendation emails. When you're **Actively looking**, these emails will be sent more frequently by default. We originally planned to roll this out earlier, but other work got in the way and we had to push this back. We're currently looking to get this out in January.

For the folks working on these features, the original verbiage seemed adequate. Obviously we were wrong. We're currently updating the wording, and going forward we'll work harder to have feature copy reviewed by fresh-eyed folks that aren't on the implementation team living and breathing those features every day.

Last thing, there are a few other places where we're standardizing terminology around the term "matches". Most notable is the tab title on the default [job search results page](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs), and in the occasional right sidebar contextual prompts:

[image]

Thanks for the post.

**Update 2015-12-14:**

We've rolled out new copy as follows:

> You’re currently marked as **actively looking** for a job. Is this still correct? If you are actively looking for a job, we’ll prioritize your CV and work hard to get you the maximum possible matches with companies as quickly as possible. If you're not actively looking, you can still mark your CV "open, but not actively looking" and we'll send you fewer, more selective matches.

Comment: It is still not clear what you mean by the word "Maximum". Does it mean there is a limit for the job search? Does it mean employers can't find you anymore?

Comment: Hmm, I don't understand the first question - can you expand? "Maximum" is more of a rate-over-time descriptor. By prioritizing your CV in the database, you're more easily found by employers, so there's simply a greater chance of being messaged. Users marked "open, but not actively looking" can still be found, it just takes some digging on the employer's part. So they can still receive messages, but there will tend to be fewer over time. All else being equal, that makes the rate of messages *with prioritization* the maximum over time.

Comment: Well, classic case of technical misunderstanding. For you those terms are familiar and obvious, but that's not the case for the end users, which I believe I represent at least partially. Anyhow, you say that "You’re currently receiving maximum job matches" means "The chance of employers to find your CV in Careers is the highest possible"?

Comment: I agree, thanks as always for for helping us see things from the end user's eyes. Your paraphrasing is correct. We additionally sought to use loose terminology that could encompass the rate of job recommendation emails (by default, when marked "actively looking" you'll receive these emails more often than when marked "open, but not actively looking").

Comment: Interesting. I have "Open, but not actively looking" but never got a single email, so all of this is totally new to me. Wonder what the OP here thinks about all of this, maybe for him it's clearer. Will ping him to have a look, thanks for your patience so far! :-)

Comment: Ah, the job recommendation email feature is still being built :) Shooting for January 2016.

Comment: Shadow Wizards rephrasing makes this clearer than the "maximum job matches". Since this is via email (and only three sentences long), I think the slightly more verbose phrasing would be helpful. Even with the explanation you've provided here, from the email it's not clear at all what "maximum" means.

Comment: As an aside, will there be a limit to how long you can be "actively looking"?

Comment: @Andy, no, there is no limit. You can be "actively looking" indefinitely. However, we are now requiring that every 6 weeks, actively looking job seekers re-confirm their job search status. (Email reminders go out at the 3 week mark.) This is because we've found that most users, after finding a job, do not come back to downgrade their job search status. That degrades the ranking quality of that field in our candidate database. Going forward, once a job seekers gets a new job, nothing will be required of them to ensure they are eventually appropriately re-indexed.

Comment: Cheers, much clearer now!